# Logout user when deleted from Parse data browser

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a couple hundred users that I need to remove from my parse app. However, when I delete the user accounts the users are still able to use the app fully without a problem. Is there anyway to "force" the logout remotely? Or what else would you suggest? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the user is being cached on the device and I don't think parse has a remote way to clear cached data on there. I like to put a user refresh(now fetch since refresh is deprecated) function when app opens to get the latest data for that user.

You could put a `fetch` function when the app opens and if it returns a specific error, it would mean the user doesn't exist and then set the current user to `nil`. I'm not sure which error it returns and I'm at work so I can't try it right now. I would hope that if the user doesn't exist, it would return `kPFErrorUserWithEmailNotFound = 205`...

Here are the error codes: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Constants/PFErrorCode.html

You will have to give it a try but I am thinking something like this (sudo-code):

```
post.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (post: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let someError = error {
        if someError = kPFErrorUserWithEmailNotFound {
            // User doesn't exist!
        }
    } else {
        // User exists and is fetched successfully
    }
}
```